# Why is my style sheet not linking to my HTML file?

Tags: html, css, gradient

So I am trying to get my background for the html file to show up as a gradient. For example, like this: http://uigradients.com/# However, my stylesheet is not linking to my HTML file so not only are my fonts not working, but neither is my gradient.

So essentially, here is what my index file looked like before I messed with it: http://crwirth.github.io and essentially all I am trying to do is make the background a gradient.

Here is my HTML file:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster'       rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- CSS
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"  media="screen">

</head>
<!--–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<body>
    <div class="element">
            <h1><a id="line1" class="categories" title="shortblurb1"  font-family="'Lobster', cursive" font-weight="normal" text-align="left" ;>Welcome, I hope you enjoy everything you encounter here:</a></h1>
            <h2><a id="line2" class="categories" href="https://github.com/crwirth" title="shortblurb2" font-family="'Lobster', cursive" font-weight="normal" text-align="left" ;>My GitHub</a></h2>
            <h2><a id="line2" class="categories" href="https://wirthrcody.wordpress.com/" title="shortblurb2" font-family="'Lobster', cursive" font-weight="normal" text-align="left" ;>My Blog</a></h2>
            <h4><a id="line5" class="categories" href="https://twitter.com/codyrwirth" title="shortblurb5" font-family="'Lobster', cursive" font-weight="normal" text-align="left" ;>Follow me on Twitter</a></h4>
            <h5><a id="line6" class="categories" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/wirthcodyr"title="shortblurb6" font-family="'Lobster', cursive" font-weight="normal" text-align="left" ;>Connect with me on LinkedIn</a></5>
                    <style>
                    </style>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ok, and here is my CSS file:

```
background: #ee0979; /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #ee0979 , #ff6a00); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to left, #ee0979 , #ff6a00); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */


html {
    background-color: #ee0979;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
    text-align: left;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top:  10px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
     }

 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


 a {
         color: black;
         font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
         font-size: 3.1em;
         text-align: left;
         padding-left: 40px;
         padding-top: 15px;
         padding-bottom: 15px;
 }
```

Comment: Is it in the same directory?

Comment: Please check (maybe even post) your directory structure as @ImAtWar said. Additionally, avoid using inline (i.e. in your HTML) styling. It makes the code unreadable, high duplicated and hard to modify in the future.

Answer (score 0):

the code here in your question is fine, but in your site exists a bad reference to the css file

[image]

Comment: Good catch @JulioSilva. I would suggest updating the href to `https://crwirth.github.io/stylesheets/stylesheet.css`. I checked and the file is there.

Comment: Yeah it is really weird, so the only way that I could get it to work was by using inline style within the HTML document, otherwise my CSS sheet just refused to link to my HTML document. And what is really weird is that I noticed when it did eventually like to my HTML document it would totally void the fonts and the gradient background.